# Insert Data to State in React Native

Tags: react-native, insert, state

I have a list data and a input type for add data, so I make state for save data and rendering it. I want when I type text in TextInput then I enter so data will added. but for this issue, screen must to be refresh for data added.

```
const [dataSubjects, setDataSubject] = useState([
    {
      id: "PPKN",
      name: "Pendidikan Pancasila dan Kewarganegaraan (PPKn)",
    },
    {
      id: "BI",
      name: "Bahasa Indonesia (BI)",
    },
    {
      id: "MAT",
      name: "Matematika (MAT)",
    },
    {
      id: "IPA",
      name: "Ilmu Pengetahuan Alam (IPA)",
    },
    {
      id: "IPS",
      name: "Ilmu Pengetahuan Sosial (IPS)",
    },
    {
      id: "SBDP",
      name: "Seni Budaya dan Prakarya (SBdP)",
    },
    {
      id: "PJOK",
      name: "Pendidikan Jasmani, Olahraga, dan Kesehatan (PJOK)",
    },
  ])

const HandleSubmit = (name) => {
    setText("")
    setDataSubject((prevSubject) => {
      return [{ name, id: Math.random().toString() }, ...prevSubject]
    })
  }
```

This is a code for state data and function add data

```
<TextInput
                    visible={inputSubject}
                    mode="outlined"
                    placeholder="Type other subject…"
                    underlineColor="transparent"
                    value={text}
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: theme.colors.surface,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      borderRadius: 4,
                      flex: 1,
                    }}
                    onChangeText={handleChangeText}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => HandleSubmit(text)}
                  />
```

this is a TextInput code

Comment: Please explain your issue and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to add whatever you type in `<TextInput/>` as a new item in `dataSubjects`? If you are you can add an item to an array by using either of the two:

1. `Array.prototype.unshift()` to addd an item at the start of the array
2. `Array.prototype.push()` to add an item at the end of the array

Specifically, you can try something like this:

```
const HandleSubmit = (name) => {
    setText("")
    setDataSubject(dataSubjects.unshift({name: name, id: Math.random().toString()})
  }
```